# How do I randomly generate non-repeating numbers even after page reload?

Tags: javascript

**Question:** How do I generate non-repeating numbers even after page reload? (Example: 0 -> 100, I would get 10 once, and never again until seeing every other number.)

**Preferred Answer:** Code block or explanation showing how to generate non-repeating numbers that won't repeat after reloading the page.

Comment: Please add your research and how you already tried resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to save the 'seen' numbers in a form of an object in a cookie or localStorage, for example like that:

```js
const seenNumbers = {
  51: true,
  64: true
}
```

Then every time you load the page, you load this array and try to generate a new number. Before using it, you check whether it is in `seenNumbers` and if it is, you try to generate a new one until you get a new number that was not used before. After that, you add it to the `seenNumbers` and save the cookie.

Don't forget to have the logic in case of `seenNumbers` have all the numbers, then your code will try to generate new items forever. To avoid that, first check the number of items in `seenNumbers`, and if it equals the number of possible numbers, you do not generate any numbers.

Comment: OP's "until seeing every other number" =>
Your "if it equals the number of possible numbers," + "clear all numbers and generate new number" instead of "you do not generate any numbers".
(Up-voted your answer)